# How to retrieve the RA (Router Advertisment) Received by My PC?

Tags: ipv6

I want to see all the RA (Router Advertisment) Received by My PC.

Where I can found a uch information on my ubuntu linux system

Comment: Please do not cross-post.

Answer (score 1):

Tools like tcpdump and wireshark are specialised in capturing network packets and decoding them for you. Both of them support router advertisements.